# PhoneGap/Cordova: where is the console output?

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to get the console output on my browser when trying out PhoneGap app through their Developer App. However, when trying to read the ouput on Firefox, this appears:

> The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.

Looking around, it seems that Cordova ovverides the default console behavior, presumably to be used with its [console plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console/blob/master/doc/index.md) (however, it also doesn't work without it).

My question is: where exactly can I find this output, if not in the browser window? I've seen some answers around that mention the Xcode console view, but I'm not using iOS. What now?

Answer (score 8):

There are a variety of options detailed [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap). Your most likely option is Chrome's remote debugger:

> Chrome Remote Debugging
>
> If you are doing Android PhoneGap debugging and have an Android 4.4 device and Chrome 30+, you can use the [new WebView Debugging tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews) added in Android 4.4. If you are using Cordova 3.3 or higher, this is already supported, and only requires the Debuggable flag in your AndroidManifest.xml. For Cordova 3.2, you will need to enable WebView debugging using some code, or by use of a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In a Cordova application, you can view the console output of your web application by using the remote debugging feature provided by the Cordova WebView. Here's how you can do it:

1. Ensure that your Cordova app is running on a device or emulator/emulator.
2. Connect your device/emulator to your development machine.
3. Open Chrome browser on your development machine.
4. In the address bar, enter chrome://inspect and press Enter.
5. You should see a list of connected devices and emulators. Find your Cordova app in the list and click the "inspect" link below it.
6. This will open the Chrome Developer Tools for your Cordova app. From here, you can switch to the "Console" tab to see the console.log output of your web application running within the Cordova WebView.

By using the remote debugging feature, you can inspect and debug your Cordova app just like you would with a regular web application in the browser.

Note: Remote debugging works with Cordova apps running on Android and iOS platforms. Make sure you have the necessary SDKs and developer tools installed for the respective platforms.